# How to output a char**

Tags: c++, pointers, char

How would one go about outputting a char** received from a function?

Say I have:

```cpp
char** foo = magicFunction();
```

Magic function will return a char**, but I do not know how the function works or the length of the char**, and the length of the char*s that it holds. (I am using a library that does this, and I am substituting the function for magicFunction() )

If I try to access the properties with brackets:

```cpp
std::cout << foo[0][0];
```

all I get printed out is `0`. When I try to increase the second bracket accessor, I get strange symbols, and it is probably memory that I shouldn't be accessing.

I have also tried dereferencing:

```cpp
std::cout << *foo;
std::cout << **foo;
```

but I still only get `0` printed out.

When I print just foo:

```cpp
std::cout << foo;
```

I get the hex address: `0x562e4699dda0` (although it fluctuates every time I run the program)

Comment: What do you mean by "I still get 0". You cannot get 0 as output in all your experiments. Not without a segfault at least for `**foo` after `*foo` being shown as 0.

Comment: Hard to say anything. You have no documentation on the function whatsoever?

Comment: when I print foo, `std::cout << foo;` The address that foo points to is being printed. I see in the console `0x...` What I mean by I still get 0 is 0 is the only thing displayed in the console

Comment: Debugging around the address you find inside `foo` might be helpful.

Comment: "I see in the console 0x..." and "0 is the only thing displayed in the console" seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @Yunnosch 0x... is the hex address and 0 is just 0 by itself

Comment: Exactly. And which of the two describes what you see in the console?

Comment: Please quote the output you see for each of your experiments.

Comment: @user4581301 It is webkit2gtk JSCoreAPI `jsc_value_enumerate_properties`. It's more header files than I can bother looking through, so I am just going with the documentation. I have asked the specific question for it, but since no one answered, I asked a more general one

Comment: If the code does not print as expected, then you have to first ensure that the returned data is in the expected format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, the array of pointers will be terminated with a NULL, and the strings are usually terminated with a '\0' character. So for printing your data I'd try:

```
for( char **ptr = foo; *ptr != NULL; ptr++ ) {
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`. (if >= c++11)

Comment: `nullptr` is a relatively new thing. `NULL` will work anywhere.

Comment: Just pointing out that this is also how argv is passed to main: `char **argv` so the data is most likely in a similar format as an array of pointers to char arrays which is why this answer is likely a good one.