# Segmentation fault when outputting a char**

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, char

This is a follow up to [How to output a char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514698/how-to-output-a-char).

Using the code:

```cpp
char** foo = magic() // Pretend magic() is a function that returns a char**

for (char** ptr = foo; ptr != NULL; ptr++)
  {
    std::cout << *ptr << "\n";
    std::cout << ptr << "\n\n";
  }
```

I get a segmentation fault. I am trying to print out every element of the char**. Further details are in the question I am following up from.

This is the output I get from `valgrind --leak-check=yes`:

```
==10274== Thread 1:
==10274== Invalid read of size 8
==10274==    at 0x88DF010: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8A436A8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8A47DB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88DA1D0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8727045: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x882EDFD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x891D7E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88284AE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88299FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x882A6C9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0xBF2FCF4: WTF::RunLoop::performWork() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.13.7)
==10274==    by 0xBF7BF68: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.13.7)
==10274==  Address 0x38 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10274== 
==10274== 
==10274== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10274==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x38
==10274==    at 0x88DF010: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8A436A8: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8A47DB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88DA1D0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x8727045: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x882EDFD: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x891D7E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88284AE: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x88299FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0x882A6C9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37.37.6)
==10274==    by 0xBF2FCF4: WTF::RunLoop::performWork() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.13.7)
==10274==    by 0xBF7BF68: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.13.7)
==10274==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==10274==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==10274==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==10274==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==10274==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==10274==
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `foo` point to?

Comment: Now is a golden opportunity for you to learn how to use a debugger to run your program one line at a time, examine the values of all variables, and observe your program's logical execution flow. This looks like a very simple bug that you should have no problem figuring out by yourself in your debugger. This is what a debugger is for. Learning how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @Beta It points to a char** More details are in the previously linked question. Specifically, it is the return value of jsc_value_object_enumerate_properties() from WebKit2GTK+

Comment: `char** ptr = foo; ptr != NULL; ptr++` should be `char** ptr = foo; *ptr != NULL; ptr++` . Note the derefrence applied in the conditional test. That is assuming that `magic()` returns a pointer to sequence of `char*`, where the end-of-sequence is delimited by a null `char*` (so it would appear, but this is a wild-arse guess because there isn't any evidence beyond broken code to support that assumption). And fyi, you really should check the value of `foo` before embarking on anything past that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am doing all of this to try to figure out the value of foo, I'll read more on pointers to pointers, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WhozCraig answered this question in a comment:

`char** ptr = foo; ptr != NULL; ptr++` should be `char** ptr = foo; *ptr != NULL; ptr++` . Note the derefrence applied in the conditional test.

I needed to check if the value was null, not the location.

Answer (score -2):

The only logical explanation is that your char** array from your magic function does not terminate with a NULL.

Comment: No, the actual problem is the `ptr != NULL` comparison, see comments.

Comment: Ah yes. Didn't notice that detail.